# How to pass an array/objects with spacebars to a meteor template?

Tags: templates, meteor, spacebars

I am trying to construct a meteor template for simplifying creating radio buttons on a form. I would like to be able to pass an array or object as an argument through spacebars to the template. How can I pass an array/object as an argument or is this even possible?

Template:

```html
<template name="radioButton">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">{{radioLabel}}</div>
  {{#each getRadioOptions}}
  <label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="{{radioOptionID}}">
    <input type="radio" id="{{radioOptionID}}" class="mdl-radio__button" name="{{radioID}}" value="{{optionID}}">
    <span class="mdl-radio__label">{{optionLabel}}</span>
  </label>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Template helper:

```js
Template.radioButton.helpers({
    getRadioOptions: function () {
        console.log("getRadioOptions called");
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.radioOptions);
        return this.radioOptions;
    },
    radioOptionID: function() {
        return this.radioID+"-"+this.optionID;
    }
});
```

Attempted spacebar notation:

```
{{> radioButton radioID="sampleID" radioLabel="Sample Radio Buttons"
    radioOptions=[{optionID:"option1",optionLabel:"Option One"},
                  {optionID:"option2",optionLabel:"Option Two"}] }}
```

After running this notation and looking at the browser console, I get back this: (which shows that only `null` was passed for `radioOptions`)

```
getRadioOptions called
Object {radioID: "sampleID", radioLabel: "Sample Radio Buttons", radioOptions: null}
null
```

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to pass json through from spacebars. Strings, scalars, and variable names yes (and variables can refer to objects obviously). Happy to be proved wrong but just haven't seen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost got it right, except that you can't give the data as a javascript array but need to use a JSON string, i.e., use:

```
{{> radioButton radioID="sampleID" radioLabel="Sample Radio Buttons"
    radioOptions='[{"optionID":"option1", "optionLabel":"Option One"}, {"optionID":"option2","optionLabel":"Option Two"}]' }}
```

Note that you need to use quotation marks around the field names, too, because it's JSON and not javascript!

Then, in the helper, parse the string:

```
    getRadioOptions: function () {
        console.log("getRadioOptions called");
        console.log(this.radioOptions);  // string
        return JSON.parse(this.radioOptions);  // array
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an object in an #each in spacebars. It has to be an Array. This should appear in your console.

Because Meteor include underscore, what you often pass is `_.toArray( myObject )`.